# Evil cursor change by state

Tags: evil, cursor

Until today, when I was in the normal state in `evil`, the cursor was a block, and it would switch to an I-beam when in insert state.  Something changed, however, and the cursor is now always the I-beam.  How can I get the old behavior back?

More generally, how do I change the cursor appearance according to `evil`'s different states?

Comment: An aside: A good way to find the variables Dan referenced in his answer is to use `apropos`. You can hit `C-h a` (`apropos`), type a search ("evil cursor"), and hit `RET` to find the documentation of any matching functions, variables, commands, etc. Helm has a built-in source for this as well: `helm-apropos`.

Comment: @nanny +1 for mentioning `apropos`. Note, however, that **`C-h a`** is bound to **`apropos-command`** by default, which will only list matching *commands*. If you want `apropos-command` to consider [non-interactive functions](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3556/504), you'll have to do `C-u` `C-h a`. The `apropos` command (which *will* show both commands and variables) is not bound to a key by default.

Comment: @itsjeyd: whoops, that was my bad on the keybinding.  I edited @nanny's comment from `apropos-command` to `apropos` -- turns out I had rebound `C-h a` to `apropos` a long time ago, forgot, and assumed it was the default.

Comment: @Dan Oh, the pitfalls of having moderator privileges... ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The variable `cursor-type` controls how the appearance of the cursor, defaulting to `t`, which uses the cursor specified for the frame (see the docstring for options).  If you'd like the cursor to default to a block, you can `(setq cursor-type 'box)`.

However, `evil` provides a number of different cursors for the different states, which you can adjust to give you a visual reminder of what state you're in when you're typing:

- `evil-normal-state-cursor`
- `evil-insert-state-cursor`
- `evil-visual-state-cursor`
- `evil-motion-state-cursor`
- `evil-replace-state-cursor`
- `evil-operator-state-cursor`

The docstring states that each of these:

> May be a cursor type as per `cursor-type`, a color string as passed
>   to `set-cursor-color`, a zero-argument function for changing the
>   cursor, or a list of the above.

So, for example, if you wanted a yellow bar 5 pixels wide in insert state and a purple-filled box in normal state, you could do the following:

```
(setq evil-insert-state-cursor '((bar . 5) "yellow")
      evil-normal-state-cursor '(box "purple"))
```

See the docstring for `cursor-type` for your options in adjusting the cursor.

Comment: Do you know by any chance, how to configure the cursor for minibuffer? Seems like it always stays as it is configured for normal mode.

Comment: @Yuki: if you mean the appearance, I do not know off the top of my head.  If you want evil bindings in the minibuffer, follow the links in the discussion on [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35796/using-evil-in-the-minibuffer) and/or take a look at [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/ccdunder/5816865).

Comment: Any way to change the box's color in the TUI?