# Using evil in the minibuffer

Tags: key-bindings, evil, minibuffer

`evil-mode` does not seem to bind keys in the minibuffer.  Is there a way to use `evil` in the minibuffer?  It's hard to use Vim-style keybindings everywhere BUT the minibuffer.

Comment: Implement it and submit a PR.

Comment: The closest thing I know to doing this is if you want to just use vim-style keybindings to edit :ex commands (ie. those that you type after typing `:`).  You can do that by using the `q:` command.  Even if it doesn't quite do what you want, it's super useful and well worth learning.

Answer (score 9):

PR [#1059](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/pull/1059) implemented this. Turn it on like this:

```
(setq evil-want-minibuffer t)
```

Watch out not to become too evil! `:D`

Comment: By the way, it was merged.

Comment: Thank you SO_MUCH for this!

Comment: Is there an update to this which allows visually seeing which evil state the minibuffer is in? (For example, `viper` does this by changing the minibuffer text color.)

Comment: To be clear, I mean specifically seeing the `evil` state in the minibuffer in a *terminal*. In the GUI, the cursor is visual indicator enough, but sadly in many terminals the cursor doesn't visually change between insert and command mode. (Worst case scenario I can eventually figure out and copy what `viper` is doing to change minibuffer "face" depending on it's state, and figure out how to do something similar, but if something exists out-of-the-box that would be nice.)

Comment: Answering my own comment (I will eventually fork this into its own question, although I do think it's very relevant here too): there is no such feature in Evil that I've been able to find, but I eventually figured out [how to implement it fairly easily](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/home/blob/fd8900671f14709f0a693ee58e749f6a3b02eeca/.emacs#L102-L117).

Comment: As promised, I converted my last two comments into [it's own question and answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76860/how-to-get-a-minibuffer-state-indicator-for-evils-evil-want-minibuffer/),