# buffer-file-name is a function, so why doesn't M-x buffer-file-name work?

Tags: buffers, files, functions, interactive

When trying to run it I get

```
M-x buffer-file-name [No match]
```

But it has a function help entry via `C-h f` and I can evaluate it with `M-: buffer-file-name`. So why isn't it accessible via `M-x`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`buffer-file-name` is a *function*, but not an interactive *command*.  `M-x` calls `execute-extended-command`, so can't be used on non-command functions.

For more information, see [What is the difference between a function and a command?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-command).

Comment: However it's worth mentioning you can run M-: (eval-expression) and evaluate "(buffer-file-name)" in the mini-buffer or in ielm.