# What's the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?

Tags: buffers, window, frames, files

When posing questions on this site, people sometimes talk about ["windows"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Window.html#Basic-Window) when they mean ["frames,"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html) and ["buffers"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Buffers.html) or ["files"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Files.html#Files) when they mean "windows."  So:

***Q:*** **What is the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?**

(I'm posing this question in the spirit of [this Q&A combo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-command): to promote correct use of the terms.)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Emacs predates contemporary window-based operating systems, so its
terminology also predates the current terms.  Unfortunately, it means that new users and experienced users sometimes have trouble making themselves understood to each other, since they're using the terms in different ways.

In brief:

- "Frames" are to Emacs what "windows" are to everything else
- "Windows" are subdivisions of frames (think "window panes")
- "Buffers" hold the contents you display/edit in windows
- When we "open a file," we are, technically, opening a buffer
  that "visits" that file

The following annotated screenshot illustrates these points.

[image: annotated screenshot]

- This Emacs session has two *frames* (blue outline) -- what, for
  most other programs, we would call "windows."
- There are a total of three Emacs *windows* (red outline) open: one in the left
  frame, and two in the right frame.
- The single window in the left frame is displaying the `scratch`
  *buffer*.  It is not connected to (i.e., visiting) any *file*.
- The top window in the right frame is displaying the *buffer*
  `example.org`, which is, in turn, visiting the *file*
  `~/path/to/example.org`.
- The bottom window in the right frame is displaying the
  [*indirect buffer*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html)
  `example2`, which has the same contents as the buffer
  `example.org` in the top window.

So here's the summary:

- [**frames**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html) are what you call "windows" in basically all of your
  other software
- [**windows**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Window.html#Basic-Window) are divisions of *frames*
- [**buffers**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Buffers.html) hold the stuff that you display in *windows*
- *buffers* may or may not be [**visiting**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html) (i.e., be associated with) a [**file**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Files.html)

Comment: Fantastic introductory summary, great graphic. For the full pedantic detail, there's one other thing to know about Emacs "frames": they extend the graphic-user-interface concept of multiple independent overlapping floating windows to the text-user-interface, that is, the terminal. So when running Emacs in the terminal, you *still* have frames at your disposal, it's just that (in contrast to a GUI) you can only see one at a time (unless you use tmux or GNU Screen). In practice you will usually only use and want one frame when running Emacs in the terminal, but the option is still there.

Comment: @PhilHudson: great addition, thanks.  I only ever use Emacs in the GUI, so didn't know about the frames-on-the-terminal point you added.

Answer (score 11):

I would point readers to (1) The **glossaries** of [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Glossary) and (2) the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glossary.html) for such information.

Also to the EmacsWiki [Newbie](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbie) page, which has lots of good introductory information about such things. And to the Emacs manual in general, which also introduces such things well: **`C-h r`** then **`i`** followed by typing whatever you want to learn about, e.g., `window`.

The EmacsWiki page linked from its *glossary* for entry **window** includes this graphic, which shows a *frame* with 3 *windows*, and indicates the menu bar for the current buffer and the mode lines of the windows.  The 3 *buffers* shown in the windows are named `*Help*`, `drews-lisp-20`, and `shrink-fit.el`.

[image: Emacs frame, windows, and window parts]

(There are other combinations of things that could be asked about, BTW, if one really wants to ask such questions.)

Comment: +1 Pointing readers to the glossaries and the Emacs manual is the right answer for such standard answers so as to avoid misleading new users.