# How can I disable the resize grip?

Tags: window

After updating my system my emacs windows have a resize grip in the bottom right corner. Is there a way to get rid of it?

The grip does not appear on any other windows.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: By "emacs windows" you mean Emacs frames? I think your window manager is in charge of that, not Emacs. See "[What's the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13583/5296)"

Comment: Hmm... I'm using the tiling wm i3 so I'd be surprised if the wm was adding the grip. I'll check out this link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize grip comes from your GTK theme and you need to disable it via GTK config or by not compiling Emacs with GTK toolkit.

You can check your toolkit version with `M-x version` (it should return message similar to *"GNU Emacs 24.5.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, **GTK**+ Version **2**.24.28*…").

Now you can set a GTK theme like e.g. *Numix* which already handles your issue or adjust your current theme by adding following changes to `~/.gtkrc-2.0` (if Emacs is compiled with GTK2):

```
style "default-style"
{
  GtkWindow::resize-grip-height = 0
  GtkWindow::resize-grip-width = 0
}
class "GtkWidget" style "default-style"
```

or to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (if Emacs is compiled with GTK3):

```
* {
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-default: false;
}
```

Above examples are only presented as a guide; for details about adjusting GTK themes please consult your distro's documentation (or GTK documentation directly).