# How well does evil work with all emacs modes?

Tags: evil

I heard about Evil-mode, but will it work in all windows? I mean, emacs is more than text editor, and every specialised window has it's own hotkeys. Are there hotkey conflicts between Evil-mode and these?

Comment: By "window," you might mean ["mode"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html), but if not, see [What's the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame).  Please do some basic reading on [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html) and [Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) to understand how the two work together, and then about the specific modes you plan to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just go out and say it: Evil has compatibility problems.

And why shouldn't it? It's a complete re-architecturing of the traditional Emacs keybinding model. Of course it can't do everything perfectly. However with that said, **it's nothing you can't fix with sufficient skill.**

I built my personal config around `evil` from the very beginning, and I've bumped into annoying niggles here and there, and I just fix them as I go. It ends up being a good deal of work in the long run, but the result is an Emacs that's perfectly fitted to your taste, and that's what Emacs for, after all.

With that said, here's a few things to note:

- Most `major-modes` that deal with actual programming languages work fine. It's the buffers that don't visit files (e.g. `magit`) where most of the problems occur.
- You always have `evil-emacs-state` (<kbd>C-z</kbd> by default) which should emulate regular vanilla Emacs pretty well.
- `evil` already has integration for a good number of packages.

---

That said, if you don't want to spend the effort of blazing your own path, you might be in the market for [`spacemacs`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs), which should have sensible defaults for almost anything these days.