# next-error and multiple frames

Tags: frames

I have a multi monitor setup and I typically have two Emacs frames, each filling a monitor.

I use `display-buffer-reuse-window (reusable-frames . T)` as my only customisation.

One thing bugs me in my workflow, I call `next-error` a lot and it will move the point to the next error in the compile buffer, and open the bad code in the window that I started in, but the focus remains in the compile buffer!

Is there a way to make the focus change frame when calling `next-error`? (when it needs to)

Right now I need to type `C-x 5 o` after every `next-error` when I'm using two monitors.

I've tried adding advice to go to the other frame after, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: To clarify terms, please have a look at [What's the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame)

Comment: The following link contains an example of how to target specific frames and windows to displaying a particular buffer **How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame**:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18346785/2112489

Comment: "*the focus remains in the compile buffer*". That sounds like a bug, to me. Consider reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Preferably, provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file) - include any settings (e.g. customizations) needed to repro it.

Comment: @dan which term needs to be clarified?

Comment: @lawlist everything opens where it is supposed to, this is a matter of focus.

Comment: @drew OK I'll do that. Can you think of a minimal command that would create some errors in a compile buffer for a file? Maybe I could use Emacs source code as the example directory.

Comment: Maybe just `M-x grep` some files? Grep output (search hits) are considered "errors" in this regard.