# From eshell or ansi-term can I open a file in the same window without a new instance of Emacs?

Tags: window, eshell, ansi-term

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a clever way in Emacs when in a shell, can I directly open a file without having to open it in another Emacs instance.

Comment: how about using **C-x C-f** and type the path to file?

Comment: When you say "buffer," do you mean "window"?  See [What's the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean in the same window, not buffer.

From eshell its simple. You can run emacs lisp functions by simply typing them into eshell. This means you can type

```
find-file file.txt
```

to open file.txt. You could also make a nicer alias to this so you could do something like type "emacs file.txt" to do the same thing. The emacs wiki page on eshell aliases has several examples of this.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias

Answer (score 1):

check out `dired-jump`. It uses the current shell directory.

Comment: It would help to point out that `dired-jump` is in the `dired-x` library, which is not loaded by default.

Comment: My bad. Take a look at http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/09/24/dired-jump/

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide info about `dired-jump`: what it does, how to obtain it, etc. Otherwise this risks being deleted as lacking content and being essentially a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [with-editor](https://github.com/magit/with-editor) in order to do that but you have to be running emacs as a daemon.

I don't know a solution to do that without using emacs as a daemon, if you ever find out I really am interested as I haven't yet investigated further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but I have an eshell alias to open up files the same way I would in a terminal

```
alias emacs find-file $1
```

Then from eshell, if I want to open up a file I just need to type `emacs $FILENAME` and it will open the file in a new buffer.