# how do I customize spacemacs default buffer

Tags: spacemacs

I would like to make some change on  spacemacs's default buffer `*spacemacs*`,like
move recently files and projects to left and show my TODO list in the right or bottom from another file

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Please see [What's the difference between a buffer, a file, a window, and a frame?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame) so that we're all sure we're using the same terms in the same way.

Comment: Sorry for that, after read that question, I have known that what I mean is buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [emacs-dashboard](https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard) ? It is

> A shameless extraction of Spacemac's startup screen

that

> - Displays an awesome Emacs banner!
> - Recent files
> - Bookmarks list
> - Recent projectile projects list (Depends on `projectile` package)

they're working to make it easily customisable, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for something more along the lines of **`Workgroups2`**, a session manager for emacs that saves and restores open buffers along with thier locations and sizes. Also supports multiple workspaces.

Comprehensive info is available at readthedocs: [Workgroups2 - Emacs Session Manager](http://workgroups2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

And git: [Workgroups for Emacs](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2)

- Emacs works differently than other editors you may have used in the past and Spacemacs is really "just" a configuration of layers and extensions that make Emacs more accessible to new users. A key difference, as Dan points out, is that *everything* begins in a buffer... and is only later written to a file type.
- For instance, having the Scratch buffer always available is very handy. One can immediately enter anything here (an org TODO, a Clojure script, a LISP fragment).
- It only *becomes* something else when you *do* something *to* the buffer; that is, when you save it to a file (foo.org, foo.clj, foo.lisp, etc). Saving a buffer *as* something changes its nature from general to specific, from potentiality to actuality.

  > This has interesting philosophical considerations!

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to change the startup buffer (or spacemacs-buffer as it is called) and I found https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/55p1td/dont_like_the_new_footer_or_customizing_your/ where basically says that the design of the page is done in  spacemacs/core/core-spacemacs-buffer.el (https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/core/core-spacemacs-buffer.el). And I did so, I didn't want to see the release-notes (they are meaningles because now all the development is done in the development branch) and I wrote

> (defun spacemacs-buffer//notes-insert-release-note ())

in my .spacemacs file in section dotspacemacs/user-config