# Create a function that returns a new function definition

Tags: functions, elisp-macros, defun

I'm creating a modular system for my use of `Emacs`, so I can call modules on the fly, as I need them. Just like a lazy call, but I must explicitly call them.

Anyways, I found this riddle, I want a function `lw/define-loadable` such that

```lisp
(defun lw/define-loadable (fn-name mod-name)
  (defun fn-name ()
    (interactive)
    (load! (concat "../modules/" mod-name))))
```

when I call

```lisp
(lw/define-loadable "lw/load-chinese" "chinese.el")
```

Will have the same effect of calling

```lisp
(defun lw/load-chinese ()
  (interactive)
  (load! "../modules/chinese.el"))
```

Currently, the call will define the funtion `fn-name` as it were hard-coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a macro, it is easier and this is what macros are for:

```el
(defmacro lw/define-loadable (fn-name mod-name)
  `(defun ,fn-name ()
    (interactive)
    (print (concat "../modules/" ,mod-name))))

;; Example call:
(lw/define-loadable my "you")
(my)

;; "../modules/you"
```

But if you insist on using a function, this will do:

```el
(defun lw/define-loadable-2 (fn-name mod-name)
  (fset fn-name
        (lambda ()
          (interactive)
          (print (concat "../modules/" mod-name)))))

;; Example call
(lw/define-loadable-2 'my2 "you")
(my2)
;; "../modules/you"
```

This function creates a closure for every command you bind.

Note, that you have to use a symbol as argument in order to generate a valid function binding. If you need the argument to be a string, then use `(make-symbol fn-name)` inside the macro or function.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Can I follow you on GitHub? I haven't found any links in your profile.

Comment: I try to keep logins for various services separated ...

Answer (score 2):

I too would use an Elisp macro, such as @jue's answer shows.  But I'll mention that you could also do this:

```lisp
(defun lw/define-loadable (fn-name mod-name)
  (fset fn-name `(lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (load! (concat "../modules/" ,mod-name)))))

(lw/define-loadable-2 'my2 "you")

(symbol-function 'my2)
;; ->
;; (lambda nil (interactive) (load! (concat "../modules/" "you")))
```

`fset` is a *function*; it evaluates its arguments.
The backquoted `lambda` sexp constructs the function definition (as a list with car `lambda`) similarly to what a macro does.

You could also do the concatenation at function-definition time:

```lisp
(defun lw/define-loadable (fn-name mod-name)
  (fset fn-name `(lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (load! ,(concat "../modules/" mod-name)))))

(lw/define-loadable-2 'my2 "you")

(symbol-function 'my2)
;; ->
;; (lambda nil (interactive) (load! "../modules/you"))
;;                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Finally, you can also use `defalias` in place of `fset`. See `C-h f defalias` for the difference.