# Defmacro: Create functions from a list o functions

Tags: elisp-macros, defun, defmacro

I have this code:

```el
(defmacro with-ignore-mouse-events (&rest body)
  "Macro to ignore mouse events before evaluating BODY."
  `(progn
     (when (input-pending-p)
       (let ((event (read-event)))
         (if (mouse-event-p event)
             (let ((button (event-basic-type event)))
               (if (eq button 'mouse-1)
                   (ignore)
                 (setq unread-command-events (list event))))
           (setq unread-command-events (list event)))))
     ,@body))

(defun mwe-function-1 ()
  "MWE function 1"
  (interactive)
  (unwind-protect
      (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
    ;; UNWINDFORMS
    (read-string "function 1 executed")))

(defun mwe-function-2 ()
  "MWE function 3"
  (interactive)
  (unwind-protect
      (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
    ;; UNWINDFORMS
    (read-string "function 2 executed")))

(defun mwe-function-3 ()
  "MWE function 3"
  (interactive)
  (unwind-protect
      (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
    ;; UNWINDFORMS
    (read-string "function 3 executed")))

(defvar mwe-function-names '(mwe-function-1 mwe-function-2 mwe-function-3))
```

I want to generate modified version of the functions like in the following example:

```el
(defun mwe-function-1* ()
  (interactive)
  (with-ignore-mouse-events
   (mwe-function-1)))
```

I tried:

```el
(defmacro generate-mwe-star-functions (&rest function-names)
  "Macro to generate mwe-function-* functions."
  `(dolist (func-name ,@function-names)
    (message "%s*" func-name) ;; The string built here is correct...
    (defun ,(make-symbol (format "%s*" func-name)) ()
      (interactive)
      (with-ignore-mouse-events
       (intern func-name)))
    ))

(generate-mwe-star-functions mwe-function-names)
```

But I'm getting lost in the mechanism of back quoting (at least).

Where am I wrong?

**Edit.** The question suggested as a duplicated of mine does not explain how to loop a list of functions to define other functions. I thing this make the task a bit more complicated.

This is evidenced by the fact that the solution proposed by the user who (probably) flagged my question as a duplicate does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a function that returns a new function definition](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70483/create-a-function-that-returns-a-new-function-definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

```el
(defun generate-mwe-star-functions (functions)
  "Generate starred versions of the given functions, where original
functions are wrapped with the `with-ignore-mouse-events' macro"
  (dolist (func functions)
    (let* ((func-name (symbol-name func))
       (starred-func-name (intern (format "%s*" func-name))))
      (defalias starred-func-name
        `(lambda ()
           (interactive)
           (with-ignore-mouse-events
             (funcall ',func)))
    (format "Starred version of the function `%s', where the original function is wrapped with the `with-ignore-mouse-events' macro" func-name)))))
```

I followed db48x's suggestion, using `defun` instead of `defmacro`, and Phil's suggestion to use `defalias` instead of `fset` in order to add a docstring to the functions.

Comment: I suggest quoting `%s` in the docstring: `\`%s'` (so that the final version has a quoted function name).

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that IFF you're using `lexical-binding` for your library then you could skip the backquote/unquote, as `func` would already be a lexical variable for the lambda, and so `(funcall func)` would be sufficient.  That ought to have byte-compilation benefits (the macro would need to be known at compile time).

Comment: I think I'll need to delve deeper into this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no reason at all for this to be a macro. Just make it an ordinary function. If you really want to fix the quoting, search for duplicate questions about quoting in macros; it is a very common question.

Edit:

The [answer you mentioned in the comments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70483/create-a-function-that-returns-a-new-function-definition) has the perfect solution for you. Instead of using `defun` inside of a macro, use `fset` inside of a function. Like this:

```lisp
(defun generate-mwe-star-functions (function-names)
  "Generate mwe-function-* functions.  FUNCTION-NAMES is a list of symbols."
  (dolist (func-name function-names)
    (fset (make-symbol (format "%s*" (symbol-name func-name)))
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (with-ignore-mouse-events
              (funcall func-name))))))
```

If you really want to use a macro for some reason, the main problem is that you compute `func-name` inside the code generated by the macro, but try to substitute it into the same code with a comma. Everything that is substituted in with a comma is evaluated when the macro is compiled, and the code inside the backquote is only called later when the code is run. Thus you either need to compute `func-name` *outside* the backquote so that it exists to be substituted in with a comma, or you need to remove the comma. Which you prefer is up to you.

You can no doubt find a dozen other people asking the same macro question where the answer is to move something out of the backquoted code.

Comment: 1 - Your response seems more like a comment than an answer to me.
2 - Of course, I did some research before writing this question, and one of the things I found in these searches is that many recommend using macros for this kind of operations. Take a look here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70483/15606
3 - If I were able to solve my problem on my own, I wouldn't have written this question. I've spent several hours trying different approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your function this way `(generate-mwe-star-functions mwe-function-names)` but it doesn't work. No new function is defined. At least not with the expected names.

Comment: Did you see the part where I changed the argument to a list of symbols, instead of a list of strings?

Comment: In my question I use `(defvar mwe-function-names '(mwe-function-1 mwe-function-2 mwe-function-3))` that I think is a list of symbols. Where did you see a list of string in my question?

Comment: Oh, I just went off of the fact that you fed `func-name` directly to `concat` which only accepts strings. The problem must be somewhere else then. Run `(trace-function 'fset)` to log every call to `fset`. When you run `generate-mwe-star-functions` it will pop up a log window to show them to you.

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to be an easy problem to solve? ;-) I ran `(trace-function 'fset)` and then `(generate-mwe-star-functions mwe-function-names)` but no log window appeared.

Comment: If you don’t have a “*trace-output*” window somewhere then something horrible has gone wrong and you have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Also, I’m leaving for the evening. Good luck.

Comment: As we're talking about interactive functions, I'd suggest using `defalias` rather than `fset` for ease of generating and adding a docstring for each of the new functions.  (Each docstring can trivially say that it's a version of `\`<func-name>'` which is wrapped by `\`with-ignore-mouse-events'`.)