How to correctly define functions with defun inside a macro?
I have the following code (built following my previus question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80426/15606):
(defvar my-list 
  '(("my-function-one" "Message 1")
    ("my-function-two" "Message 2")
    ("my-function-three" "Message 3"))
  "List of functions' names/Messages.")

(defun generate-my-functions (list)
  "Generate my-functions* from LIST."
  (dolist (infos list)
    (let* ((func-name (intern (car infos)))
           (message-text (cadr infos)))
      (defalias func-name
        (lambda ()
           (interactive)
           (message ',message-text))
        ;; Docstring:
        (format "Displays the message: %s." message-text)))))

(generate-my-functions my-list)

This code defines three functions, equivalent to the following:
(defun my-function-one ()
  "Displays the message: Message 1."
  (interactive)
  (message "Message 1"))

(defun my-function-two ()
  "Displays the message: Message 2."
  (interactive)
  (message "Message 2"))

(defun my-function-three ()
  "Displays the message: Message 3."
  (interactive)
  (message "Message 3"))

Instead of using a function like generate-my-functions, I need to use a macro that defines these functions automatically, and within that macro, I need to use defun instead of defalias.
I tried the following code:
(defmacro generate-my-functions (list)
  `(dolist (infos ,list)
     (let* ((func-name (intern (car infos)))
            (message-text (cadr infos)))
       (defun func-name ()
         (interactive)
         (message "xxx: %s" ,message-text)))))

(generate-my-functions my-list)

However, this code defines a function literally named "func-name" instead of using the value of func-name. I am struggling with how to correctly quote and expand the variables to achieve the desired result.
Additional Info: I need to use defun instead of defalias because I want to define functions that take arguments. I tried the following code:
(defun generate-my-functions (list)
  "Generate my-functions* from LIST."
  `(dolist (infos list)
    (let* ((func-name (intern (car infos)))
           (message-text (cadr infos)))
      (defalias func-name
        `(lambda (&optional only-message)
           (interactive)
           (let ((STRING ,message-text))
             (if only-message
                 (message STRING)
               (insert STRING))))
        ;; Docstring:
        (format "Inserts or displays the message: %s" message-text)))))

But this approach doesn't work as expected.
Could you help me understand how to correctly define macros that generate functions with defun and handle arguments properly? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I admit I don't fully understand why, but the following code, created by following the example found here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46430948), seems to work:

Macro that defines functions without arguments:

(defmacro generate-my-functions (list)
  `(dolist (infos ,list)
     (let* ((func-name (intern (car infos)))
            (message-text (cadr infos))
            (docstring (format "Displays the message: %s." message-text)))
       (eval `(defun ,func-name ()
                (interactive)
                (message ,message-text))))))

(generate-my-functions my-list)


Macro that defines functions with arguments:

(defmacro generate-my-functions (list)
  `(dolist (infos ,list)
     (let* ((func-name (intern (car infos)))
            (message-text (cadr infos))
            (docstring (format "Prints or Displays the message: %s" message-text)))
       (eval `(defun ,func-name (&optional only-message)
                ,docstring
                (interactive)
                (if only-message
                    (message ,message-text)
                  (insert ,message-text)))))))

(generate-my-functions my-list)

Although I managed to write the code I needed, I will accept any answer that explains, in the simplest way possible, the logic behind this code.
