# how to get region start and region end from the whole buffer as variables to call another func

Tags: buffers, debugging, commands, interactive

```
(defun buffer-to-shell()
  (let (buffer mark-whole-buffer)))
  (shell-command-on-region start end "sed s/foo/bar/") ;; start, end not defined
  )
```

As you might see there are undefined variables `start` and `end` in the function call for `shell-command-on-region`.

I would like the function `buffer-to-shell` to just mark the whole active buffer and pass it's region fields to the shell command function. I do not know how to get those to fields out of the result of `mark-whole-buffer` which I am assigning to the local variable `buffer` (which also may be redundant.

## Solution

```
(defun buffer-to-shell()
  "push the whole buffer to shell command sed"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "sed s/foo/bar/")
  )
```

yields `Wrong type argument: commandp, buffer-to-shell`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind \`C-x 8 l\` to typing lambda (λ)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14118/bind-c-x-8-l-to-typing-lambda-%ce%bb)

Comment: Your function `buffer-to-shell` does not satisfy the predicate `commandp` - it is not a command. You need to add an `interactive` spec to make it a command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I bind my function to a key or call it with M-x?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45401/why-cant-i-bind-my-function-to-a-key-or-call-it-with-m-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a region when you're calling this function from code. You only need positions in buffer, and you can get these with `(point-min)` and `(point-max)`.