# Switch to *scratch* buffer (global-set-key)

Tags: key-bindings, commands, interactive

I am reading the Intro to Lisp Programing and got to the chapter where `switch-to-buffer` is introduced.

I tried to bind `(switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")` via `global-set-key`

But this does not work:

`(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f11>") '(switch-to-buffer "*scratch*"))`

I looked at [Bernt Hansens config](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#KeyBindings) and he defined an extra function for this.

```
(defun bh/switch-to-scratch ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

Why is this necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a function and a command?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-command)

Comment: Your `global-set-key` needs to bind the key to a **command**. You're trying to bind it to a list of a symbol and a string. See ["command" in the glossary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html).

Comment: @Drew Very helpful, thank you. ... "To make a function bar available as a command you can wrap it in a custom interactive function (foo)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following demonstrates the most commonly used method to define a keyboard shortcut using `global-set-key`.  The function `bh/switch-to-scratch` is okay "as-is".  Keep in mind that we are defining SHIFT+F11 in this example:

```lisp
(defun bh/switch-to-scratch ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*"))

(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f11>") 'bh/switch-to-scratch)
```

Alternatively, we could use the following -- keeping in mind that Emacs requires that functions activated via keyboard shortcuts be `interactive`, and `lambda` is required to make this example work:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f11>") (lambda () (interactive) (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")))
```

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there a "better" way or are they both equally suited?

Comment: If it is for your own setup, either way is fine.  If you are developing a library for others to use, then the first method is the most common and users will expect to see something like that.  That being said, I have seen popular libraries that still define a few keyboard shortcuts using the second method.  When you type `C-h k` aka `M-x describe-key`, the `*Help*` buffer is a little cleaner looking (in my opinion) using the first method and one can still jump to where the function is defined (if so desired).