# How can I pass arguments to a function called interactively?

Tags: interactive

Consider this:

```
(defun kill-arg-words (arg)
  "kill `arg' words ahead of you"
  (interactive)
  (kill-region (point)
               (progn (forward-word arg) (point)
                      )))
```

I want to call it as `M-x kill-arg-words <RET> 5 <RET>`, but instead, it does not provide me the option to type in arguments after the first `<RET>`. How can I enable this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a function and a command?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-command)

Comment: There are also other duplicates, e.g. emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54602/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to specifying the arglist of the function, you have to declare where the args come from when it is called interactively.

`(interactive)` alone declares that an interactive call should supply no arguments. Use `(interactive "n")` to instead specify that when called interactively, it should first prompt for a number in the minibuffer and then supply it as the first argument.

You really should read the help message for it. Use `C-h f` to pull it up; it goes into some detail.